# My c++ application fails to link, and i don't know why

Tags: c++, makefile, g++, sdl, gnu-make

I am currently getting back in to c++. I have been running into a problem building my application.
When i run `make` the output becomes:

```
g++ -c -Wall -I headers/ -I ../libs/inc/SDL2 -L ../libs/lib/SDL2 -L/usr/local/lib -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/lib -lSDL2 -lGL -lSDL2 -lSDL2main Debug.cpp -o Debug.o
g++ -c -Wall -I headers/ -I ../libs/inc/SDL2 -L ../libs/lib/SDL2 -L/usr/local/lib -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/lib -lSDL2 -lGL -lSDL2 -lSDL2main GameLoop.cpp -o GameLoop.o
g++ -c -Wall -I headers/ -I ../libs/inc/SDL2 -L ../libs/lib/SDL2 -L/usr/local/lib -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/lib -lSDL2 -lGL -lSDL2 -lSDL2main Main.cpp -o Main.o
g++ -c -Wall -I headers/ -I ../libs/inc/SDL2 -L ../libs/lib/SDL2 -L/usr/local/lib -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/lib -lSDL2 -lGL -lSDL2 -lSDL2main -o GAME Debug.o GameLoop.o Main.o
g++: warning: Debug.o: linker input file unused because linking not done
g++: warning: GameLoop.o: linker input file unused because linking not done
g++: warning: Main.o: linker input file unused because linking not done
```

The file structure of my project

- Makefile
- Main.cpp
- GameLoop.cpp
- Debug.cpp
- headers/

  - Main.h
  - GameLoop.h
  - Debug.h

Makefile:

```
CC := g++
TARGET := GAME
SOURCES := $(wildcard *.cpp)
OBJECTS := $(patsubst %.cpp, %.o, $(SOURCES))
DEPS := $(wildcard headers/*.h)
CPPFLAGS := -I ../libs/inc/SDL2 -L ../libs/lib/SDL2 $(shell sdl2-config --libs) -lGL -lSDL2 -lSDL2main
CFLAGS := -c -Wall -I headers/

##$(info OBJECTS= $(OBJECTS) :: SOURCES= $(SOURCES) :: EXECUTABLEOUT= $(TARGET))

default: $(TARGET)

%.o: %.cpp $(DEPS)
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) $< -c -o $@


$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS)
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) -o $@ $^
RAW Paste Data

CC := g++
TARGET := GAME
SOURCES := $(wildcard *.cpp)
OBJECTS := $(patsubst %.cpp, %.o, $(SOURCES))
DEPS := $(wildcard headers/*.h)
CPPFLAGS := -I ../libs/inc/SDL2 -L ../libs/lib/SDL2 $(shell sdl2-config --libs) -lGL -lSDL2 -lSDL2main
CFLAGS := -c -Wall -I headers/

##$(info OBJECTS= $(OBJECTS) :: SOURCES= $(SOURCES) :: EXECUTABLEOUT= $(TARGET))

default: $(TARGET)

%.o: %.cpp $(DEPS)
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) $< -c -o $@


$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS)
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) -o $@ $^
```

Currently been looking at over 60 answers on this page (and others) with no luck. :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All your `g++` calls use the `-c` option. From GCC's help:

```
 -c             Compile and assemble, but do not link
```

Your last `g++` call should not have the `-c` option.  The reason you have it is because you have specified it for all your `CFLAGS`:

```
CFLAGS := -c -Wall -I headers/
```

Removing it from there should fix your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `-c` flag from the last line where you make the executable.

From Man page for g++:

> **-c**   Compile or assemble the source files, but do not link.  The linking stage simply is not done.  The ultimate output is in the form of an object file for each source file.